# Download the files in azure using azcopy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I am trying to download the files from the blod container in azure...But its showing **Error: Unknowncommand**

Cmd:

```
AzCopy https://forecast.blob.core.windows.net/test C:\Users\Shwettha\Downloads\azcopyfiles /sourceKey:sp=rl&st=2020-07-17T12:17:25Z&se=2020-12-31T21:30:00Z&sv=2019-10-10&sr=c&sig=z9b0X4vT6DGy6zOGNffM5FVaK5jNGOTeFFWD /S /V:C:\temp\logs\azcopy.log

error:
Error: unknown command "https://forecast.blob.core.windows.net/test" for "azcopy"
```

I also tried

```
    azcopy cp "https://forecast.blob.core.windows.net/test/apollo?si=Utopus&sv=2019-12-12&sr=c&sig=qHv1ojyG2hrjrq7ZQ%2BMAVZhkpCwrXs1" "utopus/apollo/forecast/dayahead" --recursive

Error: is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone pls help me...to downlaod or list the files in the blob.
iam new to azcopy

Have tried below command

```
azcopy cp "https://forecast.blob.core.windows.net/test/apollo?si=Utopus&sv=2019-12-12&sr=c&sig=qHv1ojyG2BMAVZhkpCwrXsD" "c:/Users/Shwettha/Downloads/azcopyfiles" --recursive
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to copy the contents of directory to local.

Here's something you need to check:

1.the version of your azcopy

2.Open your cmd in your computer, and navigate to the location where the azcopy.exe is.

3.the sastoken you're using, please follow the screenshot below to generate the sastoken(In azure portal):

[image]

4.suppose you have a blob container named `test8`, and the container has a directory named `ccc`. now if you want to download all the blobs inside the directory `ccc`, please use the command below:

```
azcopy cp "https://yy1.blob.core.windows.net/test8/ccc?your_sastoken" "d:\bbb" --recursive
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the error and posted my error in the question section pls help me

Comment: I have followed the above steps

Comment: @Kanagambala, which version of azcopy you're using? and when you create sastoken, do you select all the options as I mentioned in the screenshot?

Comment: @Kanagambala, and as per the screenshot in your question, it seems that it's the permission error. Please follow my steps to generate a new sastoken.

Comment: ...This SAS token is created by our customer...Could u pls help me in clarifying one question. When i logged in to azure portal, i am able to doanload from the UI...but thriugh azcopy am not able to download

Comment: ...How come its possible

Comment: @Kanagambala when you logged into azure portal, the azure portal will automatically create a sastoken with correct permission to download. but when you're using azcopy, it's your business to create the correct sastoken(so you may create an incorrect sastoken).

Comment: I am not using azure portal.Customer created the blpb in their azure accaount and gave us the access. We are just transfering the files into their azure blob..to validate the files we r using azure storage explorer.

When i try to download files in Azure storage explorer UI, files are getting downloaded. But when i try with azcopy its not happening...

Comment: @Kanagambala, when you download files in Azure storage exploerer UI, it can work. then how do you login the Azure storage exploerer? I think you're using the azure account, right?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Azure storage explorer tool to login to the blob. When  **i try to download the files from the storage explorer UI, i can dowload to my local system and its working**.But when i try with `azcopy` uploading files from local system to blob is working.However Downloading files from azure storage explorer to local system is showing access denied error.

How comes from storage explorer i can downlaod but not from azcopy..Pls help me

Comment: @Kanagambala, it's the permission issue of the sastoken. please re-generate a new sasToken with full permission.

Comment: If it is the issue with the SAS token how am able to download from the storage explorer..
Is should be problem in UI also right>

Comment: @Kanagambala, you're logging the storage explorer with account name and key, right? then the storage explorer has the full-permission to do anything like upload/download. but when you're using azcopy, you use the sastoken(when generate sastoken, people can determine the permissions), not account name and key.

Comment: Then we need to generate the new SAS token with the full permission right like upload, download, list etc...

Comment: @Kanagambala, yes, re-generate it as per the screenshot in my post.

Comment: We have write permission to the blob..Is it possible to download the files to local syatem?